# How does Snowflake's storage work differently from normal relational database in the cloud, like SQL Server on Azure?

Tags: cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

> Further, how does Snowflake "columnarize" all its data?
>
> Nothing I've read has explained it well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snowflake's storage layer is decoupled from compute.  So, you could scale up and down your compute and storage separately and instantly (within a few seconds for larger instances).  Snowflake uses a proprietary storage format called [micro-partitions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html).  You can also read more about Snowflake's storage architecture in the [SIGMOD paper](http://info.snowflake.net/rs/252-RFO-227/images/Snowflake_SIGMOD.pdf).

A normal relational database in the cloud - assuming it just a Virtual Machine with the relational database installed - is the same relational database that you're used to hosting on-premise but instead it has literally been "lifted-and-shifted" onto the cloud.  So the downside of that is the compute and storage are tightly coupled.  The pain of that being you need to plan ahead more as to how much you're planning to use on your highest usage days; are being charged even when the system isn't being used; and migrations to more powerful compute or storage is more complicated, risky, and time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

The data in Snowflake is divided and stored as micro-partitions, which are contiguous units of storage.

Each micro-partition contains uncompressed data between 50 MB and 500 MB.

Grouping of rows is performed on a table and mapped into individual micro-partitions, organized in a columnar fashion.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#what-are-micro-partitions